# How to get current rows count in primefaces 5.3 in component <p:dataTable> with paginator enabled?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.3

I need to find the value of {endRecord} - {startRecord} and populate the value inside currentPageReportTemplate. How do I evaluate the value and render as a proper message?

Read primefaces cookbook, only {totalRecords},{startRecord} and {endRecord} are found. I understand most of the value instances will follow rows attribute but there will be a remainder on last page.

Comment: Look at the javascript of the paginator in the source of primefaces

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, thanks for editing. I'm wondering if everything in detail can be retrieved by getting the Paginator instance in js?

Comment: Then try to be sure...instead of wondering and i'm not saying getting the paginator instance is sufficient. you might need to override some code